# Why there are many urls using window.location.href in Javascripts?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need get current webpage' address(URL).
I do it using:

```
var PageUrl = window.location.href;
console.log('Current URL');
console.log(PageUrl);
```

For example, in http://www.infoq.com/research/dotnet-testing-tools, I want to get the url of this page, but I get many urls:

```
Current URL    
http://tpc.googlesyndication.com/safeframe/1-0-2/html/container.html
Current URL 
http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/PqAPbTuc2cR.js?version=41#channel=f35bc2aebc&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infoq.com
Current URL
https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/PqAPbTuc2cR.js?version=41#channel=f35bc2aebc&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infoq.com
Current URL
http://www.infoq.com/research/dotnet-testing-tools
Current URL 
https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=273443186033957&domain=www.…c%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey
Current URL 
http://s7.addthis.com/static/sh.99e50185.html#rand=0.853022777242586&iit=14…efab5561013%26chr%3DUTF-8%26md%3D0%26vcl%3D1&rev=v2.4.4-wp&ct=1&xld=1&xd=1
```

I only need current webpage' url(i.e.,http://www.infoq.com/research/dotnet-testing-tools), why there are many urls? How can I get the only one?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.location.href` instead.

```
var PageUrl = document.location.href;
console.log('Current URL');
console.log(PageUrl);
```

The reason is that `window` is picking up all locations not just in that document, but pages specified inside frames in that document as well.

Comment: var PageUrl = document.location.href; it also results in many urls.

Comment: Where are you calling this from?

Comment: I call this in Tampermonkey, I want to get the current URL from browser address bar. Thanks.

Comment: Is this script going to end up on a page? It looks to me as though the script in TamperMonkey is firing for every page that loads. In this case it is including pages tucked away in iframes.

Comment: Yes, I want to the script for any sites.  "// /@include     http://*        // /@include     https://*". Is there a way to only get the url exclude frame sites?

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is, is this intended to be a TamperMonkey script, or are you prototyping in TamperMonkey so that your code will eventually be called within a webpage?

Comment: I am prototyping a Chrome Plugin in TamperMonkey and hope that the code will be called within a webpage. Thanks.